# SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH being ignored on Azure web app

Tags: azure-web-app-service

So I just read in a couple of blogs that setting SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH to D:\local\repository on an azure web app can speed up NPM/WebPack build times. I tried adding this to my app's App Settings via the portal and also the .deployment script but it seems to be ignored. The Kudu documentation and a video from the MS guys both state it is supported, but it seems to be completely ignored in my case.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How did you verify it is being ignored? did you check your deployment logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not lying, setting `SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH="D:\local\repository"` will tell kudu to download your source code to web server's local drive which all filesystem related operations is performed locally as opposed to over the network (`D:\home` is mapped to a durable NFS), this is especially beneficial for IO heavy instructions (npm). However there are some small details...

1. You cannot use `.deployment` for this setting. The reason is that `.deployment` is part of your repository which is only visible to kudu after its downloaded. this workflow shows the dilemma:
   *download source code* ==> read `.deployment` ==> *change where to store source code during download...*?
2. `D:\local` is not persistent storage, it gets reset after each web server restart (which is why the TEMP folder is mapped to `D:\local\Temp`) so if you want durability use `D:\home`
3. `D:\local` could be smaller than `D:\home`. On a free site, local drive is 500MB whereas D:\home is around 1G...you need to be careful when running `npm install` when the project has a huge dependency tree

Comment: Forgot to come back and update this question. My problem was I was setting app setting in the portal on the production instance and testing in the staging slot. Stupid me. The setting does in fact work as described.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you set the SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH to D:\local\repository, it will improve the NPM/WebPack build times speed.

Here I also created a test demo on my side using azure web app continue deploy from github.

My project is net core2.0 angular template.

And I just add the appsetting in azure portal like this:

[image]

The result as below:

The details log, you could find it improve the speed of running webpack.

[image]